# My findViewById() returns null, but it shouldn't

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments, findviewbyid

My `findViewById` returns null, but it shouldn't.
As you'll see, the button is in the same XML file.

And calling `getActivity()` makes no difference at all

Here's my `onCreateView`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

    Button  request = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_request);

    return rootView;
    }
```

And here's my `fragment_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="br.com.igor.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/servic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="Sample instructions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_request"
        style="@style/button_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/servic"
        android:text="Request" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: rootView.findViewById(...);

Comment: Do as @zgc7009 said, or do the binding in `onViewCreated()`

Comment: what do you think `getView` returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getView` is returning null, not `findViewById`. Use `rootView` in place of `getView`

```
  Button  request = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_request);
```

`getView` returns the view you inflated in `onCreateView`

Comment: that's it!
I can't believe that I couldn't see it.
Thank you very much!